# How do I convert RTF to PDF from my PHP web page using OpenOffice?

Tags: php, windows, iis, openoffice.org

My OS is Windows XP, and I'm using IIS 5.1 and PHP 5.2.9.   I'm trying to call a PHP script from my PHP page in order to convert an RTF doc to a PDF, using OpenOffice.  The script works just fine when I call it directly from the command line, but I'm not having any success getting the very same script to work when  launched from my PHP web page.

When I call the script from my PHP page, the page hangs, eventually showing an error, and I've noted that I can see in the Task Manager where the soffice.bin and soffice.exe processes are running under my IIS user name.

This is the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `com.sun.star.ServiceManager': Server execution failed ' in C:\WEB_ROOT\SoftwareContract\WordToPdf.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\WEB_ROOT\SoftwareContract\WordToPdf.php(14): com->com('com.sun.star.Se...') #1 C:\WEB_ROOT\SoftwareContract\Index.php(11): word2pdf('file:///C:/web_...', 'file:///C:/web_...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\WEB_ROOT\SoftwareContract\WordToPdf.php on line 14
```

I've double-checked permissions for my IIS user in these areas:

```
C:\PHP
C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 3
C:\Program Files\Java
C:\WEB_ROOT ---- location for my php code
```

In each case, my IIS user has these permissions:  Read and Execute, List Folder Contents, Read.  And in each case there are no "denys" checked to offset the permissions.  I also gave the IIS user write permissions for the Web_Root folder where the php code resides.

This is the php which calls the conversion function, WordToPdf:

```
<?php
require_once('WordToPdf.php');

$output_dir = 'C:/web_root/softwarecontract/';
$doc_file = 'C:/web_root/softwarecontract/testdoc.rtf';
$pdf_file = 'output.pdf';
$output_file = $output_dir . $pdf_file;
$doc_file = "file:///" . $doc_file;
$output_file = "file:///" . $output_file;
word2pdf($doc_file,$output_file);
?>
```

And this is WordToPdf.php:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
function MakePropertyValue($name,$value,$osm)
{
    $oStruct = $osm->Bridge_GetStruct("com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue");
    $oStruct->Name = $name;
    $oStruct->Value = $value;
    return $oStruct;
}
function word2pdf($doc_url, $output_url)
{
    //Invoke the OpenOffice.org service manager
    $osm = new COM("com.sun.star.ServiceManager") or die ("Please be sure that OpenOffice.org is installed.\n");
    //Set the application to remain hidden to avoid flashing the document onscreen
    $args = array(MakePropertyValue("Hidden",true,$osm));
    //Launch the desktop 
    $oDesktop = $osm->createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop");
    //Load the .doc file, and pass in the "Hidden" property from above
    $oWriterDoc = $oDesktop->loadComponentFromURL($doc_url,"_blank", 0, $args);
    //Set up the arguments for the PDF output
    $export_args = array(MakePropertyValue("FilterName","writer_pdf_Export",$osm));
    //Write out the PDF
    $oWriterDoc->storeToURL($output_url,$export_args);
    $oWriterDoc->close(true);
}
?>
```

Are there any problems with my permissions, or any additional areas where I need to check permissions for the IIS user?
Does anyone have an idea why IIS failed to create the COM object, if not a permissions issue?

Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry the code looks so awful!  I put <code></code> tags around the blocks of code, but that obviously didn't help much.  Is there any way to fix it so the blocks of code are readable and not all mushed together?

Comment: Yay, now it looks fine!  That's good.

Comment: RTF to PDF in PHP on IIS.  OMG.

Answer (score 5):

Yay!!!!  With the help of a super-duper brainiac here at work, I now have a solution that actually WORKS!  Forget all the code I posted earlier, I'm not using any of it anymore.  If anyone else needs to convert word docs to PDF from PHP on IIS here's what will work:

1) Install OpenOffice, of course

2) Go here:
http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter, and download DocumentConverter.py

3) Place DocumentConverter.py in the same OpenOffice folder where soffice.exe resides, probably C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 3\program

4) Start OpenOffice as a service:

a)You can do this from the command line:

`soffice "-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager" -headless -norestore -nologo -nofirststartwizard`

b) Or follow the directions on this website and setup OpenOffice as a windows service with the proper parameters: http://www.artofsolving.com/node/10

5) From PHP run this command:

`exec('python "C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 3\program\DocumentConverter.py" path_to_doc\test.doc path_to_output_pdf\test.pdf"');`

Yay, what a neat and pretty solution!

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like open office needs to interact with the desktop and isn't allowed to since it was invoked by a service without the [SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502(VS.85).aspx) flag.