# PHP - Extract Text from Different File Formats Word/Excel/Powerpoint/PDF/RTF

Tags: php, excel, pdf, ms-word, powerpoint

I am working on a web application where users can upload different files MS Word (.doc and .docx), Excel (.xls and .xlsx), Power point, PDF, text files and Rich Text Files (.rtf).

As part of the application flow I would like to display a preview of the contents of the files in an IFrame, HTML best but I can go with text, using a PHP class

The approach I am using is:

1. Identify the extension of each file
2. Process each file differently
3. Display the text or HMTL

Is there any library that does this?

Comment: I don't think your question is of much use nor helpful. Please see as well [Stack Overflow doesn't provide product or service recommendations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/147909).

Comment: I am not asking for a service recommendation, I am asking for a solution to a problem that I have

Comment: Sure, but this website is about programming questions. And I also wonder a bit because this question (or better the questions it consists of) have been asked a numerous times. So I guess it's worth if you improve it.

Comment: I don't think there's a single solution for this; you'll have to use separate libraries for this.  I use PHPExcel for reading Excel, ot works well.

Comment: @Sarke Thanks, I will look into PHPExcel for the excel, anything for MS Word, PDF or Powerpoint?

Comment: PHPWord and PHPPowerPoint are sister projects to PHPExcel, under the new umbrella of PHPOffice on github. The long term aim is that all 3 PHPOffice projects will both read and write; but at present neither of these reads word or powerpoint files, they only write.

Comment: What platform are you on? Potentially if you are on Windows, you might be able to run an Office Reader that renders to a bitmap via a print driver - but be aware of potential licensing issues when running it on a multi-user server.

Comment: Windows would allow you use COM, If you're on Linux, then there's Open/Libre Office and PUNO

Comment: I am trying to stay within PHP specific solutions since I have no control over the final deployment platform (may be a Linux shared host)

Comment: please post your answer as an answer, not as an update to the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single library that solves the problem so I solved it using the following libraries for each file type:

a) MS Word documents - Live Docx (http://www.phplivedocx.org/2009/08/13/convert-docx-doc-rtf-to-html-in-php/)

b) MS Excel - PHP Excel (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

c) Text from PDF - class from this Pastebin http://pastebin.com/hRviHKp1

d) Powerpoint - still work in progress

I have provided more details on my blog http://ssmusoke.wordpress.com/2012/06/16/display-contents-of-different-file-formats-wordexcelpowerpointpdfrtf-as-html/

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer, instead of linking to external ressources

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task a few years ago and we ended up using OpenOffice in server mode with ImageMagick to retrieve Thumbnails images of PowerPoint documents. For some kind of presentations library.

Basically the idea is to run OpenOffice and convert your documents to PDF and then use ImageMagick to create a thumbnail image of the first page of that PDF.

This guy here uses OpenOffice with another tool to convert documents: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1046159/626621 (could help you)

Advantage of this is, I think, that an image as a preview of the document will be more telling to your users than just the text.