# How to initialize COM object in PHP

Tags: php

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `com.sun.star.ServiceManager' in C:\wamp\www\doctopdf\index.php on line 12
```

I followed all steps given from: http://www.figured-it-out.com/figured-out.php?sid=24

Still facing the same error

**CODE:**

```
  <?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    function MakePropertyValue($name,$value,$osm){
    $oStruct = $osm->Bridge_GetStruct("com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue");
    $oStruct->Name = $name;
    $oStruct->Value = $value;
    return $oStruct;
    }
    function word2pdf($doc_url, $output_url){
    echo $output_url;
    //Invoke the OpenOffice.org service manager
    $osm = new COM("com.sun.star.ServiceManager") or die ("Please be sure that OpenOffice.org is installed.\n");
    //Set the application to remain hidden to avoid flashing the document onscreen
    $args = array(MakePropertyValue("Hidden",true,$osm));
    //Launch the desktop
    $oDesktop = $osm->createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop");
    //Load the .doc file, and pass in the "Hidden" property from above
    $oWriterDoc = $oDesktop->loadComponentFromURL($doc_url,"_blank", 0, $args);
    //Set up the arguments for the PDF output
    $export_args = array(MakePropertyValue("FilterName","writer_pdf_Export",$osm));
    //print_r($export_args);
    //Write out the PDF
    $oWriterDoc->storeToURL($output_url,$export_args);
    $oWriterDoc->close(true);
    }

    $output_dir = "C:/wamp/www/doctopdf/";
    $doc_file = "C:/wamp/www/doctopdf/a.docx";
    $pdf_file = "a.pdf";
    $output_file = $output_dir . $pdf_file;
    $doc_file = "file:///" . $doc_file;
    $output_file = "file:///" . $output_file;
    word2pdf($doc_file,$output_file);
    ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert RTF to PDF from my PHP web page using OpenOffice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040780/how-do-i-convert-rtf-to-pdf-from-my-php-web-page-using-openoffice)